# How to remove the opacity of the slides that are behind in react-spring-3d-carousel?

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

There is an `opacity` given to the **backslides** that is in the **[Carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spring-3d-carousel)**

For refrence: [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/1v96j74484?view=preview&file=/src/example.js:64-88)

How to remove that opacity?

Thank You!!

Comment: you need to download the code and alter it yourself by removing the opacity

Comment: Is there any easy way to do so??

Comment: tried even with DOM handling but since the last update happens inside Carousel, you cannot handle it since it will always write `style: opacity`

Comment: Ohh ok!! I will try the hard way then!!

Comment: check here https://github.com/gutiguy/react-spring-3d-carousel/blob/master/src/components/Slide.tsx

Comment: Yes, it is set to `opacity: distanceFactor * distanceFactor` I have to change that!